# Do I say "Chris's being annoying" or do contractions not work in this scenario?

Tags: contractions

I'm just confused on how the "is" contraction would work on words that end in 's'

Comment: It looks awkward in formal prose, but could be the more felicitous rendering of actual informal conversation. And the possessive exists. / I'm not sure why this has been downvoted; where to look for non-paywalled style guidance here does not have an easy answer.

Comment: Do you mean "Do I write it?" No-one can tell whether you are _saying_ "Chris's" or "Chris is".

Comment: If you're wondering whether it's *Chris's*, *Chris'* or something else, then notwithstanding obscure rules on possessives such as *Jesus'*, I'd strongly recommend *Chris's* as most easily understood.

Comment: Yeah, it's confusing when written in some contexts, but the contraction is common in speech.

Comment: ***No-one*** would contract ***is*** to ***'s*** after a subject noun ending with /s/, because it's effectively impossible to *articulate* in real (spoken) language, so there's no point in *writing* it like that (you cant really pronounce *Jesus's the Son of God* any different to *Jesus is the Son of God*). For the possessive, both *Jesus' name* and *Jesus's name* are orthographically acceptable.

Comment: You say, "Chris is annoying." That's because the contraction doesn't work. Saying "Chris's" sounds like saying "krissiz," which is exactly how "Chris is" is pronounced. Since a contraction isn't just abbreviated writing but also reflects an altered and shortened pronunciation and since there's no altering or shortening the pronunciation but only saying it exactly the same as how the uncontracted form "Chris is" is pronounced, it's not a contraction, so you wouldn't write it as a contraction.

Comment: I pronounce "Chris's" with a schwa before the final s, whereas I pronounce "Chris is" with a short I before the final s. But clearly not everyone makes that distinction. Contracting "Chris is" to "Chris's" is correct but not especially common in writing.

Answer (score 1):

( Chris's) —Your example of a contraction between the noun, "Chris",
and the verb, "is" ( Chris's)  would seem to me to be a correct usage,
because even famous authors have written things like:
"Joe's gonna be at the party tomorrow. He rsvp'd by phone
this morning."   [ "Joe is" becomes "Joe's"].  This is certainly
a common usage.  I also think it works exactly this way EVEN
FOR NOUNS ENDING IN "S".   But when you're turning a noun
into its possessive form,  words ending with "s" have a special
rule:  they take on an apostrophe, but they leave-off the
added "s" :         "Chris' car is in the shop." (pronounced
as if the second "s" were there, but you don't write it in.)

Comment: This is absolutely right on. Chris' car and Chris's coming to the party are **pronounced the same exact way**.

Comment: Yes they are !  We're on the same page about this.   

Comment: Yeah, it ain't no tryptic.

Comment: Traditional usage is to include the final s (Chris's) except in genitives of a small number of classical and ancient names (Jesus'). Lexico recommends including the final s whenever it is pronounced, and only omitting it if you don't pronounce it. https://www.lexico.com/grammar/apostrophe